# Form validation error message is not shown completely - Flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, dart

I know that I can change the appearance of the error message by adding the `errorStyle` attribute

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      errorStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 13.5,
      ),
    ),
  )
```

but how can I change it into showing the complete error message even if it is to big for one row?

```
validator: (value) {
    if (!nameRules.hasMatch(value)) {
        return 'Bitte max. die Sonderzeichen \'_\' und \'.\' verwenden (nicht am Anfang oder Ende).';
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: validation]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this property **errorMaxLines: 3** below **errorStyle** in your **TextFormField** Widget. This property defines the maximum number of lines in your Error Message